# How to make for every object a Treeset

Tags: java, treeset

I have a project where i need to make an erp system with products in java. So lets say we have a light as a product, this light consists of parts like a screw, a light bulb etc.
So my first guess was to use a Treeset and put those parts in every products treeset. but i only have 1 class product, so if i make a new product how do i give this new product a treeset?

Here is code from the specifik class product

```
private String productID;
private String productName;
private double productPrice;
public ArrayList<Products> prod = new ArrayList<>();


public Products(String productID,String productName, double productPrice)
{
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productID = productID;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;

}
```

Comment: 'i only have 1 class product' Do you mean that you can't change this class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to be able to determine all child (and descendants of the child) products of a given product?

Comment: instead of making a lot of different products with each with its one class we have one product class.

Comment: So, what is the problem? You have one class - Products (btw, it is better to call it Product). Now, you can create as many objects of that class as you wish.

Comment: Yes but products have many parts and parts can be in multiple products. So we simple cant make for every product a sepperate class with a Treeset to put the parts in. so thats why we cant make a instance varriable in parts to set to which product it is.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer was edited. It originally suggested cloning products that were stored in a map, but this was changed to using singletons due to concerns about bloating.

If the product class has a list of child products (parts), then each of those childparts also has a list of parts.

To fetch the immediate children of the product you could have a getPartIDs() method which only returns the elements in the list of childPartIDs. 
To fetch all the parts that make up this product you could have a method getAllComponentIDs() that will recursively walk the list of child parts and return a list with all the parts.

Once you have created a product, I suggest you store it in a map by name. I'm currently assuming that singleton for each type of product is acceptable. Then you would deal with productIDs and counts rather than instances of the product.

This would look something like the following (note it is only pseudocoded, it won't compile):

```
protected Hashtable<String,Product> productsMap;

public static void CreateProductType(String productId, String productName, dobule ProductPrice, String[] partProductIDs)
{
    // TODO: error case checking
    Product newProduct = new Product(productID, productName, double productPrice, partProductNames)
    productsMap.add(productID, newProduct);
}    

protected Product(String productID,String productName, double productPrice, String[] partProductIDs)
{
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productID = productID;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

public String[] getPartIDs()
{
   return partProductIDs;
}

public static String[] getPartIDs(String productID)
{
   Product p =  productsMap.get(productID);
   return p.partProductIDs();
}

public static String[] getAllComponentIDs(String productID)
{
   Product p =  productsMap.get(productID);
   String[] parts = p.getPartIDs();
   foreach (String productId : parts) {
       // add all child component ids to an array/list and return it
   }

}
```

Comment: This looks like a solution to our problem but what if we have like a thousand parts and we need to clone them then our database gets to full we want every part only once but we want to be able to add them to multiple products.

Answer (score 1):

You should use maps as pulekies suggested, but not in the way he's suggested.  Each Product can include a map of its children.  Not sure why you mentioned bloating your DB since this is all about reference.  There's no cloning of objects involved.

```
private String productID;
private String productName;
private double productPrice;
public Hashtable<String,Product> childProducts;


public Products(String productID,String productName, double productPrice)
{
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productID = productID;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

public Products(String productID,String productName, double productPrice, Products[] newChildProducts)
{
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productID = productID;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;

    AddChildProducts(newChildProducts);
}

public String GetProductID()
{
    return productID;
}

public void AddChildProduct(Product product)
{
    InitializeChildProducts();
    childProducts.put(product.GetProductID(),product);
}

private void InitializeChildProducts()
{
    if (childProducts == null)
    {
        childProducts = new Hashtable<String,Product>();
    }
}

public void AddChildProducts(Product[] products)
{
    InitializeChildProducts();
    for (Product prod : products)
    {
        childProducts.put(prod.GetProductID(),prod);
    }
}

public Hashtable<String,Product> GetChildProducts()
{
    InitializeChildProducts()
    return childProducts;
}
```

Comment: I had initially suggested creating an instance of each product type, and then fetching and cloning them whenever needed, but modified my solution to use a singleton due to his bloating concerns. I'll update my answer to reflect this.